# How do I get the file name of the file opened by JFilechooser?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Currently I have

```
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("src\\MovieBoxOffice\\MovieFiles");
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(openJButton);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
        try
        {
             File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
             String filename = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
(....rest of code)
```

so filename is the FULL path. 
It looks something like

```
F:\Project3\src\MovieBoxOffice\MovieFiles\November2015.txt
```

I want it to end up getting just

```
November2015.txt
```

It'd be even better if it's just November2015

I can't seem to find a method that just straight up gets the file name.

I tried using the split method.

```
String[] str = filename.split("\\");
```

so I can get the last item of the array, which would be the file name.
But that line of code is throwing exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
```

How can I get just the base filename?

Comment: `selectedFile.getName()`.  Seriously, don't convert it to a `String` to begin with, `File` has to many nice methods, like `selectedFile.getParentFile()` will return you `File` reference to the path of the file!

Comment: WOW, I swear I've been searching through all the methods. I can't believe I couldn't find  getName() after all this time... Thank you so much.

Comment: Yep, I live in that forest to, too many trees :P

Comment: `JFileChooser` doesn't open files. It *selects* files. You open them.

Comment: @EJP  right, my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selectedFile.getName()`.  Seriously, don't convert it to a `String` to begin with, `File` has to many nice methods, like `selectedFile.getParentFile()` will return you `File` reference to the path of the file!

For example...

```
File selectedFile = new File("F:\\Project3\\src\\MovieBoxOffice\\MovieFiles\\November2015.txt");
System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
System.out.println(selectedFile.getParentFile());
```

Which outputs...

```
November2015.txt
F:\Project3\src\MovieBoxOffice\MovieFiles
```

So, the answer is, ditch `filename`, use `selectedFile`